# Not Receiving JSON object into my Zend Controller

Tags: json, zend-framework

Am am successfully parsing and sending JSON values from my client for my server side controller to receive and decode

```
$("#test2").click(function() {
    $.ajax({                    
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/expensetypes/add",                 
        data: JSON.stringify(wrapFormValues($('#expensetypes'))),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg){
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            }
        });
    });
```

However in my controller the code `$this->getRequest()->getPost()` doesn't seem to receive the JSON object that my client is sending though *Firebug* clearly shows that my *JSON* object is being parsed and sent.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

> print_r($this->getRequest->getParams());

and see what that shows you

Comment: It returns the value "Array" only and not the JSON object am expecting.

Comment: what does wrapFormValues do? I take it $('#expensetypes') is a form? did you try to leave out wrapFormValues and just stringify the form?